# Python requests module not following redirect for file download

Tags: python, python-requests

Trying to automate downloading a .zip file from the link [here](https://schools.clever.com/files/badges.zip?fromEmail=1&randomID=5f9cffb0ee8c81418ac2e019) (the links will always be different, but they are always in this format):

If this link is entered into a web browser, it downloads a file called **Badges.zip**. When trying to download it from `Python` with the code below, it saves to **Badges.zip**, but the `.zip` is not an archive. It's some `Google Analytics` code. It's like the requests module is not redirecting all the way to the file. I've tried get, head, trying to stream the download, and lots of other ways and I can't get it to download the file correctly. Here's the current code I'm using:

```
import requests
url = "https://schools.clever.com/files/badges.zip?fromEmail=1&randomID=5f9cffb0ee8c81418ac2e019"
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('c:/data/Badges.zip', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

I'm open to any ideas. Have tried other modules and get similar results. I'm even open to kicking off external utilities if needed like wget or curl (which I haven't had any luck with yet either).

Note that the Clever Badges in this download have been voided to prevent use.

Thanks!

Comment: I clicked on the link and it is a login page. I think that you need a direct link to the file you want to download. This page proably starts a download without asking but it is not a direct file link.

Comment: Doh. You're right. I didn't realize this required authentication. Thought I was logged out of everything before trying all this, but my credentials were still cached. I'll work out the authentication piece, even if I have to do it through Selenium or something. Thanks for checking!

Comment: Maybe they have some kind of api to directly download files with a token instead of having to log in every time.